# Which rendering/template engine should I use for node.js?

Tags: performance, memory, node.js, rendering-engine

Right now, I'm using jqtpl in my node's express.  However, my coworker said that it took a lot of memory under load testing.

So:

1. Is it a problem with express or the rendering engine?  is there any configuration (like view cache) I should do to reduce memory usage?
2. What is the characteristic of different rendering engine? e.g. jade, jqtpl, ejs...etc

Please advice.

Comment: jqtmpl was not designed to be used on the server. [Comparisons of performance](http://unknownerror.net/2011-04/nodejs-javascript-template-engine-performance-comparison-and-optimization-of-some-6610). Of course Jade and EJS are safe bets. Do your own benchmarking

Comment: i tried Jade at first but had my problems getting used to the syntax, so i'm using EJS now. i didn't really feel a difference performance-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the benchmarks using `NODE_ENV=production`, by using the development environment you have to load and compile the template each time.